# $\int_B( x^2+y^2) dxdydz$ where $B=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2\le 1; 0\le z\le 1\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to take the integral:

$$\int_B (x^2+y^2) dxdydz$$

where

$$B=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2\le 1; 0\le z\le 1\}$$

so I did like this:

first I integrated $x^2+y^2$ over $z$ from $0$ to $1$:

$$\int_0^1 (x^2+y^2 )dz = x^2+y^2$$

Then I integrated $x^2+y^2$ this over the circular region $x^2+y^2\le 1$ giving

$${\int\int}_{B_2} (x^2+y^2) dx dy$$

where $B_2$ is the circumference of radius $1$

This integral in polar coordinates gives me:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 p^2 p dp d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
*[as wolfram alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28integrate%20p%C2%B3%20dp%20from%200%20to%201%29dt%20from%200%20to%202pi)

but the answer on the book is

$$\frac{7\pi}{12}$$

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you did looks right. Maybe a typo in the book?

Comment: $\pi/2$ looks good to me. Must be a typo in the book. Maybe a substitution for another q, but forgot to change the answer.